# NSFontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits changes my font name

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the font's name is "Helvetica" at beginning, I call the `font.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits:` to create a font descriptor, and then create a newFont with the descriptor. But the new font's name becomes `Arial-ItalicMT`. How does it happen? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL; DR**: adding `withFamily()` will get you the expected result:

```
let font = NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)!

let descriptor = font.fontDescriptor.withFamily(font.familyName!).withSymbolicTraits(.italic)
let newFont    = NSFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: 18)!

print(font.fontName)    // Helvetica
print(newFont.fontName) // Helvetica-Oblique
```

---

#### The long answer:

An `NSFontDescriptor` is like filtering criteria for fonts. Based on how you configure this object, the system will find matching fonts. Let's examine the descriptor of your first font:

```
let font = NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)!
print(font.fontDescriptor)
/*
NSCTFontDescriptor <0x1016168d0> = {
    NSFontNameAttribute = Helvetica;
    NSFontSizeAttribute = 18;
}
*/
```

A font with name of Helvetica and size 18. So far so good. Now, let's check your second descriptor:

```
let descriptor = font.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.italic)
print(descriptor)
/*
NSCTFontDescriptor <0x10161b0e0> = {
    NSCTFontTraitsAttribute =     {
        NSCTFontSymbolicTrait = 1;
    };
    NSFontSizeAttribute = 18;
}
*/
```

There's no mention of Helvetica anywhere! If you initialize an `NSFont` with this descriptor, the OS wil find the first available italic font on your computer, which is `Arial-ItalicMT`. You can check by openning Font Book.

You need to specify that you are looking for an italic font in the Helvetica family:

```
let descriptor = font.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.italic).withFamily("Helvetica")
print(descriptor)
/*
NSCTFontDescriptor <0x10113baa0> = {
    NSCTFontTraitsAttribute =     {
        NSCTFontSymbolicTrait = 1;
    };
    NSFontFamilyAttribute = Helvetica;
    NSFontSizeAttribute = 18;
}
*/

let newFont = NSFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: 18)! // Helvetica-Oblique
```

To make it more generic, you can replace the string `"Helvetica"` with the `familyName` of the first `font` object.

Answer (score 0):

The instance method .`withSymbolicTraits` returns a new font descriptor that is the same as the receiver but with the specified symbolic traits taking **precedence** over the existing ones. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfontdescriptor/1469843-withsymbolictraits)

From what I've understood. The first font in rank will be return based on the [fonts included with macOS Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT206872).

In your case `.italic` will return `Arial-ItalicMT` or `.bold` return `AlBayan-Bold`